# WCF client returns error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Tags: wcf, fault

I am migrating a WPF application to Silverlight. My WPF application accesses a Web Service using BackgroundWorker. If there is any error while accessing the web service I get an extensive error message in my callback, for example

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8080/services/registration
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

In my Silverlight application, I am accessing the same web service asynchronously and now my error messages are not very useful, for example:

```
 The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

The web service has not changed - I can see the faults coming from the server on Fiddler. So the question is how can I get more detailed error messages on the Silverlight client.

My callback in Silverlight application looks like this (I am accessing the error message from e.Error.Message):

```
private void AuthenticateUserCallback(object sender, AuthenticateUserCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        this.StatusMessage = e.Error.Message;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is limitation with Browser stack due to which SL cannot access the complete exception message. Look at MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
The approach is to wrap exception into meaningful faults (which means client will always get HTTP OK 200) and perform custom exception handling on the client side.